# Copy Value from combo list on login screen to username field on new form

Tags: ms-access-2007

Newer to access...I am trying to copy the value selected from the combobox on the log in screen to a field on the new form that opens after successful login.

The field I need copied is called cmoemployee on the Login form.I need that to go to the username field on the mainframe form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have tried many different ways but I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, 
I actually know what you mean here. This can be a complete pain as the variables are deleted when you open a new form In general it is better to show what you have tried so people are able to help you fix it. Anyway, I've tried to do this so I know how frustrating it can be. There are two main ways that this can be done. You can open the form with openargs (I do not think this is a good option for you as you will have to have the openargs constantly transferring from one form to the next and will be cleared if one form misses them.

A better option would be to use tempvars which are not deleted. This is the code I used to do something similar:

I am going to assume your combobox is two columns (but only displays one) and the bound column is the primary key to an employee table. In which case this would work (or you can modify it to meet your needs)

Log in:

```
'Check Password (or however you check it

    If StrComp(txt_Password, DLookup("[Password]", "tbl_Employee", "[ID] = " & cmoemployee), 0) = 0 Then
    TempVars.Add "MyEmpID", cmoemployee.Value 'TempVars will store the combobox value
    Else
    Msgbox "Incorrect Password Please try again"
    End If
```

On Load event of mainfraim form:

```
[UserName] = TempVars!MyEmpID
```

That should get you started, so you can build the rest. Let me know if you have any questions.